# React Native - Analysis data from Firebase and display inside app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, machine-learning, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a React Native workout app using Firebase.

I would like to perform simple analysis of user data from the database and present them inside the app to the user or through notifications (Cloud Messaging).

**Example 1:** Notification: For the last 7 days, you have an average of 10 minutes on-screen time browsing the workouts section. Good job!

**Example 2:** Modal Pop-up: You have been viewing a lot of chest workouts lately, but haven't viewed any leg workouts. Here are some suggestions...

How can I implement such analysis? Is there a built-in, ready to go Machine Learning tool for Firebase and React Native? Are there any alternatives?